# Add tableview in scrollview with table scrolling disabled in Iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have scroll view with label and a table view and a button . I just want to scroll the scrollview and the table view must display all the contents but tableview must not scroll. Below the tableview i have a button. How to set the frame of the button so it comes exactly below the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to set the YourTableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can disable the scrolling the tableview.
Goto->xib->select table->Goto 1st tab->unselect the scrolling Enabled.

The answer for your Second Question.

Put the UiView in footer of your table and then place the button in that UIView you want to show in bottom.
It will always show at the bottom.

If you want to place button programmatically use following code in viewDidload method.

```
     ///--------Table Footer is Set here

     UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 44)];
     UIButton *adddays = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 260, 44)];
     [adddays setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abcd.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [adddays addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonaction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
     UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 12, 250, 20)];
     [text setBackgroundColor:CLEAR_COLOR];
     [text setText:@"Title for your button"];
     [text setTextColor:XDARK_BLUE];
    text.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:18.0f];

    [footer addSubview:adddays];
    [footer addSubview:text];
    [table setTableFooterView:footer];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you have created IBOutlets for your `scrollView`, `tableView` and `button`, and hooked them up appropriately.

I find it useful to remember that we're only messing with the y-values of a `CGRect` (`origin.y` & `size.height`) - The x-values should be set up in the xib.

I've commented this profusely to illustrate my point better, usually I would only comment where appropriate

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

// Get the number of rows in your table, I use the method
// 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' because I only have one section.

int numOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];

// Get the height of your rows. You can use the magic 
// number 46 (44 without including the separator 
// between rows) for the height of your rows, but because
// I was using a custom cell, I had to declare an instance
// of that cell and exctract the height from 
// cell.frame.size.height (adding +2 to compensate for
// the separator). But for the purpose of this demonstration
// I'm going to stick with a magic number

int rowHeight = 46; //Eww, Magic numbers! :/

// Get a reference to the tableViews frame, and set the height
// of this frame to be the sum of all your rows

CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.size.height = numOfRows * rowHeight;

// Now we have a frame with the exact size of our table,
// so set the 'tableView.frame' AND the 'tableView.contentSize'
// to that. (Because we want ALL rows visible as you
// disabled scrolling for the 'tableView')

self.tableView.frame = frame;
self.tableView.contentSize = frame.size;

// Now we want to set up the button beneath the table. 
// We still have the 'frame' variable, which gives us 
// the tableView's Y-origin and height. We just add these
// two together (with +20 for padding) to get the origin of the button

CGRect buttonFrame = self.button.frame;
buttonFrame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height + 20;
self.button.frame = buttonFrame;

// Finally, we want the `scrollView`'s `contentSize` to
// encompass this entire setup (+20 for padding again)

CGRect scrollFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
scrollFrame.size.height = buttonFrame.origin.y + buttonFrame.size.height = 20;
self.scrollView.contentSize = scrollFrame.size;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could stop the scrolling the table view. But you shouldn't be adding a tableview inside a scrollview. UITableView is subclass of UIScrollView and adding one scrollView on another will create problem. I suggest you to remove the scrollview and use the tableview alone ( as the tableview itself is a scrollview).